# How to create new data frame from date range with same value in R?

Tags: r

I have an example of a data frame below:

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(1514764800, 1514851200, 1514937600, 
1515024000, 1515110400, 1515196800, 1515283200, 1515369600, 1515456000, 
1515542400, 1515628800, 1515715200, 1515801600, 1515888000, 1515974400, 
1516060800, 1516147200, 1516233600, 1516320000, 1516406400, 1516492800, 
1516579200, 1516665600, 1516752000, 1516838400, 1516924800, 1517011200, 
1517097600, 1517184000, 1517270400, 1517356800, 1517443200, 1517529600, 
1517616000, 1517702400, 1517788800, 1517875200, 1517961600, 1518048000, 
1518134400, 1518220800, 1518307200, 1518393600, 1518480000, 1518566400
), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), Al = c(NA, 
21.399, 21.399, 21.399, NA, NA, NA, 8.036, 8.036, 8.036, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 36.914, 36.914, 36.914, 
NA, NA, NA, 11.466, 11.466, 11.466, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 16.471, 
16.471, 16.471, NA, NA, NA, NA, 56.157, 56.157, 56.157)), row.names = c(NA, 
-45L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would like to create a new data frame where I only take the first date from a range with the same value. Here is my expected output:

```
structure(list(startdate = structure(c(17532, 17533, 17536, 17539, 
17542, 17553, 17556, 17559, 17562, 17567, 17570, 17574), class = "Date"), 
    Al = c(NA, 21.399, NA, 8.036, NA, 36.914, NA, 11.466, NA, 
    16.471, NA, 56.157)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(startdate = structure(list(format = "%m/%d/%Y"), class = c("collector_date", 
    "collector")), Al = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

I have a large dataset like this and it would be wonderful if I can use R to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please check if the expected and input are the same

Comment: I have good news! You already have your desired output. :-).   (j/k, presumably one is meant to be different)

Comment: I must be out of my mind yesterday lol :) sorry. I have edit the input and expected data frame.